# What's white and comes in three parts?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

1. You likely use me every day,
   Every time you go outside.
   Sound like I'll make you go away;
   Also used by those you ride.
2. You might see me every day
   If on SE time you waste.
   It's kind of like your daily pay;
   Addictive once you've had a taste.
3. I'm essential for your life;
   Bovine means I can't be seen.
   Placing me on blocks was rife
   In the old days that have been.

What's the link?

Comment: What do you mean by link

Comment: Working that out is part of the puzzle.

Comment: @Duck well, that's the question, isn't it? I mean, what *is* the link? :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The link is:

> **lace**

1 + 2:

> The first two stanzas describe **shoe** and **rep**, as jafe has already found out.

3:

> The last stanza describes **neck**: A bull neck is so thick that it cannot be seen as being separate from the head. And the neck on the choppig block was a common death penalty in days of yore.

Connexion:

> All three words can be combined with **lace**: **shoe**lace; **rep**lace; **neck**lace.

Comment: Ooh this one also fits the title! Being white and having 3 parts, with the rot13(zvqqyr/fgevat) and two rot13(ntyrgf)!

Comment: Oehm is on point as usual. Well done.

Answer (score 8):

Partial

You likely use me every day,
Every time you go outside.
Sound like I'll make you go away;
Also used by those you ride.

> shoe
>  Used by both people and horses, sounds like "shoo"

You might see me every day
If on SE time you waste.
It's kind of like your daily pay;
Addictive once you've had a taste.

> rep (as in reputation)
>  It's reward points you get for correct answers and the like

I'm essential for your life;
Bovine means I can't be seen.
Placing me on blocks was rife
In the old days that have been.

> air
>  Breathing is essential for life. Not sure of the other clues though...

Put together:

> shoe repair

No idea how this relates to the title yet...

Comment: Shoe polish can be white and shoe repair is three syllables.

Comment: @Duck so is shoe polish (shoe - po - lish) :D

Comment: Parts 1 and 2 are right. Part 3, and the final solution, aren't.

Comment: First thing that popped in mind for the 3th one is rot13(jngre, vg'f rffvnagvny gb yvir; vg'f pyrne fb lbh pna frr guebhtu vg; va gur byq qnlf gurl cynprq jngre ba oybpxf nobir n sver gb znxr vg fnsr gb qevax.) but not sure how this would help for a link :p.

Comment: Also, your way of getting the final solution *from* the three parts isn't right. It's more interesting than that :-)

Comment: @mrdeadsven: "3th" 

Comment: @3D1T0R honestly I always wrote those kind of things like that without thinking about it, and now that I see your comment I'm questioning my life xD.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, to build on jafe's answer:

Part 1 is

> Shoe (this one I did not get)

Part 2 is

> Rep

And I think part 3 is

> milk

Because of the

> Bovine reference, it being necessary for life since we all need milk as babies

and also the mention of

> blocks which I believe are blocks of ice which people would put their milk and other perishables on.

However the final solution eludes me. I believe it to be a

> three part word or phrase made up of the following wordparts

to be determined:

> ____ shoe or shoe____

And

> ____rep or rep_____

And

> ____milk or milk______

But what could it be?

> Is it Gazeulsionmaid? j/k

Edit:

Is the answer to the bovine line in part 3

> invisible as in invisi-bull?

So now I think part 3 is... (Drumroll)

> dna

So the word could contain these letters

> shoerepdna
>  per and hose

Ugh, I give up for now.. am I on to anything?

Comment: I like this answer; the explanations are well-thought... but that last line is hilarious! $(+1)$ :D

Comment: Sorry, part 3 still isn't right. And the final solution isn't going to be a 3-part word or a 3-word phrase.

Comment: Ok thanks. I just edited my answer with a new idea. Any feedback?

Answer (score 3):

Based on other answers:

**Part 1**

> Shoe, but as "Shoo!" (or go away).

**Part 2**

> Rep (reputation).

**Part 3**

> Milk or cream. Cream is made from milk, which kinda makes sense, though it's not entirely fitting with the poem.

My guess:

> **Repellent**. Based on Sho! (go away), rep (ellent) and milk/cream. It comes in three forms: cream, spray and incense-like products, making sense with the "three parts".

Comment: Sorry, Part 3 still isn't right. But your way of putting the three together is (slightly) more on-point than what jafe tried.

Comment: Wait, I thought it wasn't a word made of 3 parts? Because that was exactly what I was talking about..